# How do I set the root-layer of a MapServer WMS to queryable="0"?

Tags: wms, mapserver, getfeatureinfo, getcapabilities

## Problem

### Problem Summary

I want the response of all the MapServer WMS *GetCapabilities* requests to not show `queryable="1"` in the root layers XML node.

### Status Quo

The *GetCapabilities* response looks like this:

```xml
<Layer queryable="1">
  <Name>[value of MAP>NAME]</Name>
  <Layer queryable="1" opaque="0" cascaded="0">
    <Name>[value of MAP>LAYER>NAME]</Name>
```

The mapfile looks something like this:

```
MAP
  NAME 'SERVICE_NAME' 
  STATUS ON
  SIZE 500 500    
  UNITS meters
  SYMBOLSET '/PATH/TO/SYMBOLS'
  FONTSET '/PATH/TO/FONTSET'
  MAXSIZE 20000
  EXTENT 2513000 5401999 2604000 5501999
  PROJECTION
      "init=epsg:31466"
  END
  SHAPEPATH '/PATH/TO/SHAPE/DATA'
  OUTPUTFORMAT
    NAME png
    DRIVER 'AGG/PNG'
    MIMETYPE 'image/png'
    IMAGEMODE RGBA
    EXTENSION 'png'
    TRANSPARENT ON    
  END

  LEGEND
    IMAGECOLOR 255 255 255
    STATUS ON
    TRANSPARENT ON
    KEYSIZE 18 12
    LABEL
      TYPE BITMAP
      SIZE MEDIUM
      COLOR 0 0 89
    END
  END

  WEB
    // ...
    METADATA
    // ...
    END
  END

  // Now the layers

END
```

### Desired State

The response should look like this:

```xml
<Layer>
  <Name>[value of MAP>NAME]</Name>
  <Layer queryable="1" opaque="0" cascaded="0">
    <Name>[value of MAP>LAYER>NAME]</Name>
```

### Additional Context

- Debian Buster
- MapServer v7.2.2

`<!--  MapServer version 7.2.2 OUTPUT=PNG OUTPUT=JPEG OUTPUT=KML SUPPORTS=PROJ SUPPORTS=AGG SUPPORTS=FREETYPE SUPPORTS=CAIRO SUPPORTS=SVG_SYMBOLS SUPPORTS=RSVG SUPPORTS=ICONV SUPPORTS=FRIBIDI SUPPORTS=WMS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WMS_CLIENT SUPPORTS=WFS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WFS_CLIENT SUPPORTS=WCS_SERVER SUPPORTS=SOS_SERVER SUPPORTS=FASTCGI SUPPORTS=THREADS SUPPORTS=GEOS SUPPORTS=PBF INPUT=JPEG INPUT=POSTGIS INPUT=OGR INPUT=GDAL INPUT=SHAPEFILE  -->`

## Question

How can I disable the `queryable` attribute as default for root layers?

### My research

When I tried to find the options in the documentation all I found was "*To be queryable, each mapfile LAYER must have a TEMPLATE defined, or each CLASS within the LAYER must have a TEMPLATE defined.*" [Introduction to MapServer](https://mapserver.org/introduction.html?highlight=queryable). This does however not mention how to influence the behaviour of the root layer.

This behavior seems to have changed from the version used in *Debian Stretch* to v7.2.2. I would usually not care, but I have follow up problems due to this attribute and they did not exist in the previous version.

Comment: The change may be related to https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/issues/5404.

Comment: Hi @user30184 yeah, that seems related. A solution got merged in https://github.com/MapServer/MapServer/pull/5405, so I could just remove the root-layer entirely; but only with a newer version of MapServer as it seems. I'll have a look at the implications on that on my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Also in older versions the root layer should not appear if you use an empty  `NAME ''`.

Comment: Hi! @user30184 that solved my problem, if you want you can write the answer and I'll accept it. I just needed to add to the MAP>WEB>METADATA: `'wms_rootlayer_name' ''` as described in [WMS Server Docs](https://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html). The docs are generally talking about the root layer though and not espacially about the queryable attribute. The result is as I wanted it in my Question, the layer is still listed, but the queryable attribute is gone.

Comment: Would you rather write the answer yourself because you know now what to do better than I?

Answer (score 1):

The described desired state got achieved by adding the following line in the mapfile. This has to be done per mapfile as there is no such default available just yet.

```xml
MAP
// ...
  WEB
  // ...
    METADATA
    // ...
      'wms_rootlayer_name' ''
    // ^ this line has to be added!
    END
  END
// ...
END
```

The result will be almost exactly as described in **Desired State**:

```xml
<Layer>
  <Layer queryable="1" opaque="0" cascaded="0">
    <Name>[value of MAP>LAYER>NAME]</Name>
```

The root-layers `<Name>` tag is also gone, but more importantly the `queryable="1"` is being omitted.

---

The solution was pointed out by @user30184 in the comments.